# Changing the Page directory name in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is is possible to Change the /Page/ directory name to something like /News/ or /Stories/ or /Resources/  in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise, for a specific site collection?

Obviously this is a virtual location that I am trying to figure out how to modify.  Any thoughts?  /Pages/ is just to limited of a naming convention, even though you can create folders inside of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can change the directory name, if you are deploying your solution with some custom pages then always use module's element.xml file [Provide required path here] to do such things, otherwise if you want it for particular site collection then open your site in SharePoint Designer and rename your Pages folder resides in All Files -->`Pages`

Comment: Thank you Rishi!  Yes, this is for SP publishing sites!  Can this process also be done by the Ribbon? or from the web browser if needed?

Comment: ah, I just discovered formyself that your technique works perfectly when I am actually on the site collection from the ribbon and then simply choose to edit site in sharepoint designer, and then rename the page from that point.  Thank you Rishi for the answer!